# A Trademarked™ pack of rebuses

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, rebus

Here is a pack of rebuses:

[image: The Pack]

Eack of the above rebuses represents a famous brand/company. The relation between a rebus and the brand it represent vary from rebus to rebus (some rebuses relate in a way and others in another way, ... and so on). Also, some of the rebuses may require some should-be-known-to-everyone knowledge about the brands, hence the tag.

Your task, whether you like it or not, is to identify those brands/companies (provide some explanation as well).

**Progress so far:**

> Refer to [this wiki answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60435) to get links to all the correct answers.
>  **Solved:** A (by Beastly Gerbil), B (by puzzledPig), C (by kayzeroshort), D & E (by North), F (by curiousdannii), G & H (by Rand al'Thor), I (by thecoder16) and J (by DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb).
>  **Unsolved:** none.

---

**Hint:**

> As @MOhem already noticed, **D** and **I** are not exactly what one call a [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus). I tried covering that by adding an [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag.
>  That being said, I can confirm that **F** is a rebus, but it's a twisted rebus as it is a double-layered one.

---

<sub>**Notes:**</sub>

<sub>- All of the images used in the rebuses were shamelessly stolen from Wikipedia, and were edited using an un-updated version of Gimp.</sub>
   <sub>- The rebuses vary in difficulty, so I expect a lot of partial answers. Thus, I decided to accept the answer that solves the last unsolved rebus.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**F**:

> **Google**: in a Kiwi accent it sounds like 10 to the 10 times 10, or a [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol).

Comment: Yes that's it. Well done!

Comment: Given that this is the answer, I would be a lot happier with the rebus if you had placed the dot as a multiplication operator (at the midline) instead of as a decimal point (on the baseline).

Comment: @Hellion In Britain and the Commonwealth (including New Zealand), a midline dot is decimal point and a baseline dot is multiplication operator.

Answer (score 13):

## Full Community Wiki Answer

**Note:** The links to the answers included in this wiki answer are made such that they will take you to the answers without redirection (at least not after the first click, i.e. if it redirects you, it will only do it once). So go to the answers and upvote accordingly. The link to this wiki answer is [as follows](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60435), so if you want to include it in your answer as a back (scroll-to-wiki-answer) button, then go ahead.

A:

> 20th Century Fox -- [@BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60414)

B:

> Nike -- [@puzzledPig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60416)

C:

> Samsung -- [@kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60417)

D:

> Ferrari -- [@North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60413)

E:

> Oracle -- [@North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60436)

F:

> Google -- [@curiousdannii](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60475)

G:

> Apple -- [@Randal'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60415)

H:

> YouTube -- [@Randal'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60415)

I:

> Microsoft -- [@thecoder16](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60469)

J:

> Pepsi -- [@Agile_Eagle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/a-trademarked-pack-of-rebuses#60459)

Comment: (I think @North actually solved A first, but then shadow-edited their answer after Beastly Gerbil posted his.)

Comment: I think 'I' is Windows, if you piece the pieces together to get the logo.

Comment: @LarsW Go ahead and post that as an answer.

Comment: @LarsW And remember it's the brand/company not the product that I'm looking for. And also work a little bit on the explanation as it still weak.

Comment: This is now a complete answer!

Answer (score 11):

Is the J one,

> Pepsi

because,

> 3.14 represents the greek letter **PI** and the second image represents the capital greek letter **PSI**. Add these and we get **PIPSI** which sounds very similar to **PEPSI**

Comment: I knew there was a drink company somewhere! Nice job!!! +1

Comment: @North Thanks, but I don't think that's the answer. It was a long shot. Maybe the OP has a better answer in his mind:)

Comment: What does OP stand for here? I dont think it means "over powered"...

Comment: @North I don't know, people usually refer to the question poster as OP on forums, I suppose.

Comment: @North I believe it usually stands for "Original Poster," that is, the person who posted/ started the thread.

Comment: Correct. Well done!

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer

C

> **Samsung**: Uncle Sam + sung

Comment: OMG. There goes the hardest (I guess). Very very very Impressive. Well done!

Answer (score 7):

Partial (I'll add wiki links when complete):

A:

> 20th century fox (19xx = 20th century + fox)

B:

> (ICC [International Criminal Court] - ice = C) + inifinity * did + it = ??

C:

> American Express (American + express)

D:

> Wheel horse

Comment: Why is the second image in C "express"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I took it as you are expressing yourself (weak, I know). Couldn't think of anything else it could be though

Comment: First one is correct. Others, unfortunetly no.

Comment: There's a famous brand called "Wheel horse"?

Answer (score 7):

Partial:

I looks to be

> The Four Seasons (the hotel chain), as each photo represents a different season

And I think B is

> Nike: (justice-ice) + do, infinitive form of "did" + the clown from It --> "Just Do It," Nike's slogan

Perhaps D is

> The Pony Express?  (a horse/pony on wheels could move quite fast, hence the "express")

Comment: Neither is correct?

Comment: B is correct. The first is unfortunetly not.

Answer (score 6):

G could be

> **iProducts** (iPod, iPad, iPhone, etc.)

H is

> **Youtube** (a tube shaped like a U).

Comment: Corrent on both. Impressive!

Comment: ... though the first is supposed to be the company not its products :-P

Answer (score 5):

Is letter F

> Gap? I mean besides Nike, theres no other clothing brands. Besides that, theres also a gao between the first can to thee other two, and the other two cans also have a gap in between them, seperated by a dot.

Is letter E

> Oracle? Take the first three letters of orange (ora) then middle letter of chicken (c) and take the LAST two letters of candle, and you get ORACLE

Comment: Correct. You're getting better at rebuses I see. Congrats!

Comment: Hmmm. That would work much better if "chicken" had six letters, too.

Comment: @MOehm North's explanation is different from what I used to make the rebus. Actually it's: take the first letter from the first word, the second from the second, ... and so on. So the letter count for a word doesn't matter.

Comment: F is wrong, sorry!

Comment: Fair enough, but I still think it would have been nicer to have only six-letter words here. (And it's a bit too "enigmatic" to be a rebus for my taste. How the letters are extracted can only be guessed and I think in a rebus it should be indicated somehow, perhaps cryptically.)

Answer (score 4):

Partial:
D is

> Ferrari? Because it has a horse in its logo

Comment: Now you got it right. Already upvoted (2 hours ago).

Comment: @ibrahim I don't get it. How does a horse on wheels give this answer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, the wheel suggest its a car [company/manufacturer]. And efeFerrerereeereaeri is famously known for its horse logo.

Comment: Then it's not a rebus. (Yes, I've seen the enigmatic tag, but everything else sugets that all images are rebuses.)

Comment: @MOehm You think I should add a [tag:visual] as well?

Comment: No, I think rebus includes visual already. I've seen your note. Perhaps "rebus" shouldn't be in the title if not all are rebuses? Anyway, I sound like I'm grumpy on a Monday morning and I really don't want to. It's a fun puzzle and finding out which mechanics are used for each can be part of the fun. (And given how many people have answered it really seems like fun for the whole (PSE) family.) So I'll stop being too technical now.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir wouldn't Mustang also be correct?

Comment: @Kruga I got to admit that I included it just to complete the pack of 10 and because I run out of ideas. It's soo weak I know. It's not even a rebus.

Comment: @kruga That was my first guess

Answer (score 4):

I think letter I is

> Windows/Microsoft logo. Each of the pictures has a marking in the corner, which corresponds to a section of the windows logo. Ex. The orange leaves picture is the top left square in the logo, the green meadow picture is the top right, etc...

Comment: Yes. By replacing each season with its color. BTW, I'm looking for the brand/company so...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir edited, oops

Answer (score 3):

E - Could it be

> Fruit 'n Fibre  -> Oranges (Fruit); Hen = 'n; Burning candles = Fi(b)re

Comment: I like your thinking, but sorry, it's not correct. [North's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60436/40853) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

F is:

> Verizon.

Because:

> The end of the verizon logo looks like a square root symbol, and tin cans can be used as basic 'telephones' on the ho'RIZON

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! It's accepted practice here to hide answers inside spoiler tags, so as not to ruin the solution for anyone who wants to try the puzzle themselves. Could you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: Sorry, not correct.

Comment: Thanks you for the correction. I'm not used to the puzzling SE

Answer (score 1):

J could be...

> The OpenROV's Trident camera, it runs on Raspberry Pi!

Comment: Not correct, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

*Since we're apparently doing multiple answers for this one ...*

F is probably something to do with

> can power? tin exp? something along those lines (thanks @justhalf for this idea)

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope. :-)

Comment: I believe F is representing exponent, but I'm having a hard time finding a company related to something like "can raised to the power of (partial? is that a decimal point?) can".

Comment: @ibrahim Is justhalf's idea getting warmer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've added a hint. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I

> FourSquare - The company behind the Foursquare city guide app.  It's four squares that are different locations.

Comment: Did someone else attempt this answer before? Is that why it was voted down and marked for deletion?

Comment: Is that a company?

Comment: It's an app that's popular in the u.s. Over 10 million downloads

Comment: And the company is trademarked.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not correct. Good thinking though